# Firestore Security Rules: How to perform a collection query within firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My database structure is as follows:

`/sites/{siteId}/pages/{pageId}`

now I don't want to allow update the `isPublished` field of a **page** if there are already 3 published pages in the **pages** collection.

For this I would need to query the pages collection with "isPublished", "==", true filter and check the amount  of docs.

Is there a way in firestore security rules to achieve this

```
match /sites/{siteId}/pages/{pageId} {
 
   allow update: if request.resource.data.isPublished == true ? canPublishPage(siteId) : true 

}


function canPublishPage(siteId) {

   // how can I check number of published page at the moment?

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to calculate this kind of aggregate data from the rules.

Instead you will have to:

1. Add a counter within the `siteId` document, incremented at each page creation. You will want to use a [batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) here to update the site counter and create the page both in an atomic way. Use the [`getAfter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) function in your rules for `pageId` to verify the counter is properly incremented:

   ```
   function isCounterIncremented(siteId) {
     let counterbefore = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/sites/$(siteId)).data.counter;
     let counterafter = getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/sites/$(siteId)).data.counter;
     return counterafter == counterbefore + 1
   }
   ```
2. Check that counter from the rules when a page is updated using [`get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) in your rules:

   ```
   function canPublishPage(siteId) {
     return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/sites/$(siteId)).data.counter < 3;    
   }
   ```